# How do I add a KeyListener to an entire project?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, keylistener

I am developing an app that requires multiple JFrames. The JFrame writes to a file, then is disposed. I want to have a KeyListener listen for the same key press, throughout the entire project without having to create the KeyListener in each class. Is there a way?

Comment: Normally you'd use key bindings, but whether listener or binding it is still tied to a component. By the way, and sorry for being blunt, but your design of swapping JFrames stinks. Can't you swap JPanels via a CardLayout instead? Your users would appreciate this.

Comment: Ah, never thought of that. I easily just made the worst mistake.. Thank you though, and I guess I could just use the card layout, and add the key binding at the start of the program.

Comment: *"I am developing an app that requires multiple JFrames."*  No it doesn't.  There are a dozen different ways to include many GUI elements on one screen, look into them.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) should be used, but since I can't delete my accepted answer I have to leave this here.

Comment: @Justin: "For every problem there is a solution that is simple elegant and wrong", and this is a case in point. This won't work as it will fail as soon as you add any component to the GUI that requests focus.

Comment: correct but then he can utilize the above code to add the keylistener to any component he wishes

Comment: -1, bad solution to use a KeyListener. Terrible solution to add the key listener to every component.

Comment: @camickr agreed but I can't delete it as it's the accepted answer so what's the point in downvoting....

Comment: I gave my reasons. Plus its do discourage anybody else who reads this from using the solution. If people see an upvote, they might actually think its a good suggestion :)

Comment: Up-voted for the edit. @camickr: you may wish to do the same.